# this is a Haskell program for quick sort,

Tags: sorting, haskell, quicksort

but I get lot of error in it.[image]

I could not understand where there problem is, is it the a

Comment: Don't post images of code, but the code itself together with the error messages (as a code fragment as well).

Answer (score 4):

Whatever weird left-arrow character you're using, it isn't one GHC understands. Just write `<-` like it's the '90s again.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the left arrow (←) by enabling the [**`UnicodeSyntax`** extension <sup>[ghc-doc]</sup>](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/unicode_syntax.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

qsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = smaller ++ x : larger
    where
      smaller = [ a | a ← xs, a <= x ]
      larger = [ a | a ← xs, a > x ]
```

you can transform additional arrows with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

qsort ∷ Ord a ⇒ [a] → [a]
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = smaller ++ x : larger
    where
      smaller = [ a | a ← xs, a <= x ]
      larger = [ a | a ← xs, a > x ]
```